# How to load from an Array into PivotFields?

Tags: excel, vba

I want wo change multiple Fields in multiple pivot sheets.

Therefore i created a new Sheet where one can set the Fields. The Sheets, the Fields and the values are stored in two Arrays. This is my code it won't work on line

`.PivotFields(filterArr(i, 0)).CurrentPage = Sheets("Filter").[filterArr(i, 1)].Value`

Can somebody tell me why?

```
 Sub Filter_Change()

'Array for diffrent Sheets
Dim sheetArr As Variant
sheetArr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

'Multidimesional Array for diffrent Filters and their Values
Dim filterArr(10, 1)

filterArr(0, 0) = "Field1"
filterArr(0, 1) = C10

filterArr(1, 0) = "Field2"
filterArr(1, 1) = C11



'Go through each Sheet
For Each element In sheetArr

        'Change every Filter in the Sheet
        For i = 0 To 1

          With Sheets(element).PivotTables(1)
            .PivotFields(filterArr(i, 0)).CurrentPage = Sheets("Filter").[filterArr(i, 1)].Value
            .PivotCache.Refresh
          End With

        Next i

Next element

End Sub
```

Comment: Should C10, C11 be "C10","C11" and where are filterArr(i, 1) used ?

Comment: Yes thats probably better. I edited the code now you can see where filterArr(i, 1) is used. Sorry it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the error line into smaller steps using intermediate variables if necessary so that by using debug.print and stepping through with F8 you can identify where the problem is. Change [filterArr(i, 1)] to Range(filterArr(i, 1)) and quote the values C10 and C11. Also using Option Explicit will identify problems. For example

```
Option Explicit
Sub Filter_Change2()

    ' Sheets to process
    Dim arSheets As Variant
    arSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    ' Filter parameters
    Dim param(2)
    param(1) = Array("Field1", "C10")
    param(2) = Array("Field2", "C11")

    ' Process each Sheet
    Dim n As Integer, i As Integer, sField As String, sValue As String
    For n = 0 To UBound(arSheets)

        For i = 1 To 2

            sField = param(i)(0)
            sValue = Sheets("Filter").Range(param(i)(1)).Value
            Debug.Print arSheets(n), i, sField, sValue

            With Sheets(arSheets(n)).PivotTables(1)
                .PivotFields(sField).CurrentPage = sValue
                .PivotCache.Refresh
            End With

        Next
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```